# How to use dynamic source data in a recorded macro (VBA) when generating a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I'm encountering an issue with a couple macros I recorded to my personal workbook. The source data changes every day which is reflected in the filename. The recorded macro still has the filename from the creation day, but I need it to either update for the new filename or simply select data source from the current open workbook/worksheet. I'm pretty new to excel and vba, so a simple fix would be best. Thanks!

```
    Sub MC_PIVOT()
    '
    ' MC_PIVOT Macro
    '

    '
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "MC_20201106!R1C1:R27951C48", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
        :="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'd do something like this to create a pivottable from the data in the active sheet

```vb
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSource = ActiveSheet
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    wsDest.Name = "Pivot"
    
    'create the pivot cache first
    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
               SourceData:=wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, Version:=6)

    '...then the pivottable
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsDest.Range("A3"), _
                                 TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim this was very helpful! Have a great day!